# Django rest framework request.data raises Error

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using Django Rest Framework. Both in my view, there raises error like `request instance has no attribute 'data'` I tried a lot and didn't find anything. Do I have to add any middleware or something? How DRF retrieves data from request.POST and request.GET. My view is function based one.

```
def list(request, format=None):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = CustomerSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: What method are you using?  `request` only has a data value for POST, PUT and PATCH methods.  If you're trying it on a GET, you need to use request.query_params.

Comment: Is that a direct method definition or class based view? It either needs to have `@api_view` decorator or to be part of a class inherited from `viewsets.ModelViewSet`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`@api_view` decorator missing.To get `request.data` in DRF, either you have to use the decorator `@api_view` or extend from the `APIView` class
if you are using class-based view.

from rest_framework.decorators import api_view

```
@api_view
def list(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = CustomerSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

For class based view extend from APIView

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView

class List(APIView):

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = CustomerSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

documentation : [DRF request](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/2-requests-and-responses/)